# Async/await throwing unhandled exception

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task

I'm trying to implement exception handling from a task but I just can't seem to get it right. I've found a few examples of the pattern but no matter what I try I always seem to get unhandled exceptions from within the task itself. I must be missing something, but I can't see what. Any help would be very much appreciated.

I've tried an example I found on MSDN but that doesn't work for me:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997415(v=vs.110).aspx

And I followed the answer to this question but when I run the fix in Visual Studio it still complains about unhandled exceptions:

[ContinueWith TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted does not seem to catch an exception thrown from a started task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27896613/continuewith-taskcontinuationoptions-onlyonfaulted-does-not-seem-to-catch-an-exc)

This is the code that I initially wrote:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TestAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(t.Exception.ToString());
    }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

    Console.ReadKey();
}

static async Task<IEnumerable<string>> TestAsync()
{
    IEnumerable<string> list = null;

    try
    {
        list = await TestTask();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Caught!");
    }


    return list;
}

static Task<IEnumerable<string>> TestTask()
{
    var task = new Task<IEnumerable<string>>(() =>
    {
        throw new AggregateException("This is a test");
    });

    task.Start();

    return task;
}
```

Comment: I'm not entirely clear - what are you expecting to happen? All I see is a throw, catch, and re-throw path. That'd leave the exception unhandled.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I was hoping that the exception thrown in TestTask() would end up in the Exception property of the task it returns, but when I run this example in Visual Studio it highlights the throw in TestTask() and says that it's an unhandled exception. I was also surprised that the example on MSDN was doing the same thing.

Comment: I've updated the example code so it shows what I was trying to do a bit more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just hit continue after VS breaks, you will see it gets to your ContinueWith. It is just a quirk of the debugger because it cannot find a try/catch within your code that handles the execption.

If you don't want the debugger to stop and show you a message you will need to disable "Just My Code" in the debugger options so that the try/catch that lives inside of `Task` gets counted as the thing that catches the exception.

Comment: Wow - is that really all it is? I did notice that it got to my ContinueWith if I continued after the exception, but I was concerned that if the code was executing in a release then it would get to the unhandled exception not make it any further.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've tested the above code in release mode and it works as expected. I could see this being a bit troublesome when developing larger applications and needing to be in debug mode, but I guess that's when the 'Just My Code' option is used.